# How to make text box blank instead of hidden given an expression?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I want a text box to show, but be blank given a certain condition.  i don't want it to be "hidden" because then it doesn't look great.  Example below of what it looks like hidden.

[image: Example]

Comment: add your expression you used too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an expression. Let's say you only want to display values above zero and leave the rest blank, then you use an expression to replace the cell value with `Nothing`:

```
=IIF(Fields!DelNo.Value > 0, Fields!DelNo.Value, Nothing)
```

You could also do it with using the `Format` property. Let's say you don't want to display zeroes. Leave the cell as being the field value and make the `Format` property `#,##0;-#,##0;` (note that there is a space at the end of that format).